# What is the python syntax to tell if a string only contains numbers?

Tags: python, syntax, numbers

I think this should be fairly simple but can't seem to figure it out.

I just need the python syntax to find if a string contains only numbers.

so it would find: `'8888'` or `'1'` or `'126928428'`

but not:
`'Test'` or `'Test8'`

I searching for it in a for loop that is pulling info off a webpage with BeautifulSoup.

```
<td>203.195.237.158</td><td>8888</td><td>CN</td><td>China</td><td>Socks5</td>
```

Basically I am trying to pull the ip and port out of a long string of these.

Comment: You needd to use the [str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method ex. `'126928428'.isdigit()`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit

Comment: Ahhhhh str.isdigit.  Thanks that's what I was looking for.  I kept think int but that wouldn't work because it is a sting.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[str.isdigit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) tests if the string is composed only of characters from `'0123456789'`:

```
In [35]: 'Test'.isdigit()
Out[35]: False

In [36]: '8888'.isdigit()
Out[36]: True

In [37]: 'Test8'.isdigit()
Out[37]: False
```